# Run SQL Server generate script with data from a batch file

Tags: sql-server

My goal is to script out a database with data like you used to with the sql publishing tool that older versions of SQL Server had

I am using SQL Server Express 2017, and I know how to perform this task manually by right clicking on the database->tasks->generate scripts

Is there a .exe being called here, in older versions of SQL Server this would call sqlpubwiz.exe, and you could call this .exe from a cli, and put into a batch file.  I am looking to replace this behavior.  Can someone let me know the exe that is being called, and let me know how to script against it.

Comment: Short answer - no. Longer answer - duplicate of [generate scripts from command line](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/56616/sql-server-2012-generate-scripts-from-command-line)

Comment: is there a .exe that is called when you call the database->tasks->generate scripts

Answer (score 0):

you can use SQL Dumper, easiest way to export the script data (with Insert query)

for more information :
https://support.microsoft.com/en-in/help/917825/use-the-sqldumper-exe-utility-to-generate-a-dump-file-in-sql-server

to download the utility
https://download.cnet.com/SQL-Dumper/3000-10254_4-10514574.html